# Can someone explain please what is "EntityMoniker" and when to use it in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

What is exactly "EntityMoniker" in Dynamics CRM and when to use it. Is it used instead of the "Target" Entity?

Comment: https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e2365bd7-ee0a-4450-bb18-ede4b5f9f148/when-to-use-entitymoniker-and-dyanmicsentityentiy-in-crm-2011?forum=crm note "late bound strategy". That is, it's a *name* representing an Entity (ref. [moniker](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moniker)) which will be (later) resolved to an Entity. This avoids having to have the Entity object immediately available and in a valid state, for instance.

Comment: In the link you have listed someone says: You don't have to use EntityMoniker some  messages work with this type. A moniker holds only the guid and the entity name. The EntityMoniker type was replace by  EntityReference.

Comment: If "EntityMoniker" was replaced by "EntityReference" Why it is used when Activating or Deactivating a record and NOT EntityReference used instead?

Comment: I think there is some naming confusion going on (that I didn't help). "EntityMonikor" is a [reused] name of a property. In earlier versions (~CRM 4.0?) there was a CrmHelpers.Monikor type that has been superseded with the EntityReference type (since 2013?) - both types serve the same "moniker" or "late bound" goal.

Comment: Are you truing to say that "CrmHelpers.Monikor" in CRM 4 was known as "EntityMonikor" which Specifies an instance of an entity. And in version crm 2011 and above the "EntityMonikor" is something different? If so what it is and what is used for in CRM 2011 and above?

Comment: There is a "shared" *property name* "EntityMonikor" used in different namespaces/types/versions. The type of the property has changed depending on the type the property was defined on (from CrmHelpers, Xrm, etc). Both types (the old Monikor and EntityReference) serve the *same* purpose in the end. Use the required type. In that case that is `EntityReference` for an "EntityMonikor" property.

Comment: Ok. I see what you mean. The Message Request "SetStateRequest" has a property called "EntityMoniker" which is of type EntityReference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "EntityMoniker" is a property of the SetStateRequest class and it is of type EntityReference. While the "Target" is a property of AssignRequest, CreateRequest, DeleteRequest, ExecuteWorkflowRequest, MergeRequest and UpdateRequest classes and it is of type Entity.

Comment: Note that not all requests contain a Target property that is of type Entity, so you have to look at each request or response. For example, DeleteRequest has a Target property, but its type is EntityReference [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309673.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`EntityMoniker` is used in SetStateRequest. I have the following method, that i use to Change `Status` of any record in `CRM 2011/2013`

```
public static void SetStatus(string EntityName, Guid Id, int StateCode, int StatusCode)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Service == null)
                throw GRID.CRM.ExceptionHandler.ExceptionUtil.GetException("Connection with CRM is Lost", typeof(Common), "SetStatus");
            SetStateRequest StateRequest = new SetStateRequest();
            StateRequest.EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(EntityName, Id);
            StateRequest.State = new OptionSetValue(StateCode);
            StateRequest.Status = new OptionSetValue(StatusCode);
            SetStateResponse StateResponse = (SetStateResponse)Service.Execute(StateRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw GRID.CRM.ExceptionHandler.ExceptionUtil.GetException(ex, typeof(Common), "SetStatus");
        }
    }
```